# check the input null

Tags: java

i've found this line of code got error if the input not an number

```
int sum = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sum"));
```

the error message is

```
type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"
root cause

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"
```

how to handle the input if the input is a string or null?

thanks

Comment: using an `if` statement.

Comment: within catch i use out.println("please input a number");, but there is no output? why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what should be done if sum is not a number.

```
try{
 int sum = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sum"));
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
  //how do you want to handle it? like ask the user to re-enter the values
 }
```

Comment: within catch {} i use out.println("please input a number");, but there is no output? why?

Comment: are your sure you are catching the right exception? if you are not sure what exception will be thrown always use the Exception class

Comment: that problem fixed. but how to stop the jsp after the exception?

Comment: As a general rule, you should try to always try to catch the exception in particular (you can also catch more general ones). The right order could be catching NumberFormatException, then Exception, then Throwable. But in this particular case, catching NumberFormatException should be enough.

Answer (score 3):

You should first make sure request parameter is not null and contains numbers only using:

```
if (request.getParameter("sum") != null &&
    request.getParameter("sum").matches("^\\d+$"))
    int sum = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sum"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
int sum = 0;
try {
    sum = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sum"));
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // sum = 0. If you needed to do anything else for invalid input
    // put it here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just catch the exception and handle it accordingly:

```
int sum;
try {
    sum = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sum"));
}
catch {
    //do something if invalid sum
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Check manually (loop over the characters)
2. Catch the exception

Try this:

```
try {
  sum = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sum"));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  ... // handle if the string isn't a number
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
  ... // handle if it's null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for null before Using Intefer.parseInt and also you can check whether input contains other than numeric value

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach that doesn't involve throwing and catching exceptions:

```
String input = request.getParameter("sum");
// Validate the input using regex
if (input == null || !input.matches("^-?\\d{1,8}$")) {
    // handle bad input, eg throw exception or whatever you like
}
int sum = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

Note that this regex doesn't allow numbers too large, and allows negative numbers

Comment: +1 Good regex for ints (if a little simplistic for very large numbers)

Answer (score 1):

I see the `org.apache.jasper.JasperException` Which means this is in a JSP? If you're adding code like that to a JSP, you might want to reconsider what you're doing. Ideally, you should handle things like input validation in a controller of some sort, and then pass off results to a template of JSP for rendering.

There are many frameworks out there to help with this sort of thing, and in general they're worth using because your web application will benefit from all of the work that the framework authors have already done in the realm of security etc...

Pretty much any of the half a dozen code answers already posted will work for you though if you just want to hack it out.